# What would you use to build a new compiler for .NET?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, cil

I'm working on a new toy language that will be statically compiled to .NET's IL code.

Off hand I can think of the following to actually generate the IL, but I'm open to alternatives:

- Cecil
- ILASM

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Common Compiler Infrastructure ([AST/Code](http://cciast.codeplex.com/), [Metadata](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/)), and of course the venerable Reflection.Emit.  I don't have any experience of CCI myself, but [this page](http://cciast.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=API%20overview) seems a good starting point for the IL translation side of things.

Comment: Reflection.Emit does look promising.

Comment: Drat. Looks like it has some serious limitations.
http://blogs.msdn.com/lucian/archive/2009/11/29/the-limitations-of-reflection-emit.aspx

Comment: You might find IKVM.Reflection/IKVM.Reflection.Emit a feasible replacement too.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own language using this compiler generator.  I used it.  Its really easy to use and to understand.

[CoCo/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco/R

Comment: While certainly an interesting idea for parsing, I'm looking for advice on actually generating the IL itself after it has already been parsed.

Comment: Sorry.  With that, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

if MSIL generation per se is not of the essence, you could "compile" (translate) your language to C# and then use the regular dotnet compiler for that. I would imagine that's quite a bit easier to do, although you don't get as much scope for implementing esoteric performance optimizations and so on. Translation into a common high level language would have definitely been my first choice in any such new language situation where I was not concerned with optimizing the speed of compilation.